# Navigate through tweets (boxes) + three js

Tags: javascript, jquery, 3d, three.js, keydown

this is my situation:

I want to show twitter tweets like this: http://threejs.org/examples/css3d_periodictable.html

This is what I have now:http://nielsvroman.be/twitter/root/index.php
The boxes are tweets from the user: @BachelorGDM.

What I would like now is that there is always one selected and that you can navigate through them with the arrow keys on the keyboard.

This is my javascript code:

```
// THE TWEETS 
var data = loadTweets()

// FUNCTION SHOW THE TWEETS
function ShowTweets(){

// VARS TABLE WITH TWEETS / PLACE IN COLUMN / PLACE IN ROW
var table = [];
var column = 1;
var row = 1;

// LOOP THROUGH DATA AND CREATE TABLE WITH TWEET DETAILS + PLACE 
$.each(data, function(i) {

    // DETAILS TWEET
    var idstring = data[i].id_str;
    var screenname = data[i].user.screen_name;
    var imageurl =  data[i].user.profile_image_url;

    // 9 TWEETS NEXT TO EACH OTHER
    if(column % 9 == 0)
    {
        row++
        column = 1;
    }

    var array = [imageurl, idstring, screenname, column, row ]

    column++;

    table.push(array);
});

// VARIABLES THREE JS
var camera, scene, renderer;
var controls;

var objects = [];
var targets = { table: [], sphere: [], helix: [], grid: [] };

init(); // CALL INIT FUNCTION
animate(); // CALL ANIMATE FUNCTION

function init() {

    // INITIALIZE CAMERA
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000 );
    camera.position.z = 1800;

    // INITIALIZE SCENE
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // LOOP THROUGH TABLE ARRAY (ARRAY WITH ARRAYS IN IT)
    for ( var i = 0; i < table.length; i ++ ) {

        var item = table[i]; // ITEM IS ARRAY WITH [imageurl, idstring, screenname, column, row]
        var element = document.createElement( 'div' );
        element.className = 'element';
        element.id = item[1]; // ITEM IDSTRING
        element.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,127,127,' + ( Math.random() * 0.5 + 0.25 ) + ')'; // BG COLOR + OPACITY FROM FRAME

        var number = document.createElement( 'div' );
        number.className = 'number';
        number.textContent = i + 1; // NUMBER IN THE RIGHT TOP
        element.appendChild( number );

        var symbol = document.createElement( 'div' );
        symbol.className = 'symbol';
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = item[0]; // IMAGE SOURCE IS LINK TO IMAGE
        symbol.appendChild(img);
        element.appendChild( symbol );

        var details = document.createElement( 'div' );
        details.className = 'details';
        details.innerHTML = "" + '<br>' + item[2]; // SCREENNAME
        element.appendChild( details );

        var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject( element );
        // POSITION OBJECTS AGAINST EACH OTHER
        object.position.x = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
        object.position.y = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
        object.position.z = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;

        // ADD OBJECTS TO SCENE
        scene.add(object);

        // ADD OBJECT TO OBJECTS ARRAY
        objects.push(object);
    }

    // TABLE VIEW

    for ( var i = 0; i < objects.length; i ++ ) {

        var item = table[i]; // ITEM IS ARRAY WITH [imageurl, idstring, screenname, column, row]
        var object = new THREE.Object3D();
        object.position.x = ( item[3] * 160 ) - 1540; // X-POSITION (COLUMN)
        object.position.y = - ( item[4] * 200 ) + 1100; // Y-POSITION (ROW)

        // targets = { table: [], sphere: [], helix: [], grid: [] };
        targets.table.push(object); // PUSH OBJECT IN TABLE ARRAY (IN TARGETS ARRAY)
    }

    // SPHERE VIEW

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3();

    for ( var i = 0, l = objects.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

        var phi = Math.acos( -1 + ( 2 * i ) / l );
        var theta = Math.sqrt( l * Math.PI ) * phi;

        var object = new THREE.Object3D();

        object.position.x = 1000 * Math.cos( theta ) * Math.sin( phi );
        object.position.y = 1000 * Math.sin( theta ) * Math.sin( phi );
        object.position.z = 1000 * Math.cos( phi );

        vector.copy( object.position ).multiplyScalar( 2 );

        object.lookAt( vector );

        // targets = { table: [], sphere: [], helix: [], grid: [] };
        targets.sphere.push( object ); // PUSH OBJECT IN SPHERES ARRAY (IN TARGETS ARRAY)
    }

    // HELIX VIEW

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3();

    for ( var i = 0, l = objects.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

        var phi = i * 0.175 + Math.PI;

        var object = new THREE.Object3D();

        object.position.x = 1100 * Math.sin( phi );
        object.position.y = - ( i * 8 ) + 450;
        object.position.z = 1100 * Math.cos( phi );

        vector.copy( object.position );
        vector.x *= 2;
        vector.z *= 2;

        object.lookAt( vector );

        // targets = { table: [], sphere: [], helix: [], grid: [] };
        targets.helix.push( object ); // PUSH OBJECT IN HELIX ARRAY (IN TARGETS ARRAY)
    }

    // GRID VIEW

    for ( var i = 0; i < objects.length; i ++ ) {

        var object = new THREE.Object3D();

        object.position.x = ( ( i % 5 ) * 400 ) - 800;
        object.position.y = ( - ( Math.floor( i / 5 ) % 5 ) * 400 ) + 800;
        object.position.z = ( Math.floor( i / 25 ) ) * 1000 - 2000;

        // targets = { table: [], sphere: [], helix: [], grid: [] };
        targets.grid.push( object ); // PUSH OBJECT IN GRID ARRAY (IN TARGETS ARRAY)
    }

    renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    // ADD RENDERER TO CONTAINER
    document.getElementById( 'container' ).appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    // TRACKBALLCONTROLS => WHEN YOU HOLD DOWN MOUSECLICK

    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    controls.rotateSpeed = 0.5;

    //controls.minDistance = 500; // MAX ZOOM IN => MIN DISTANCE
    controls.maxDistance = 2500; // MAX ZOOM OUT => MAX DISTANCE
    controls.zoomSpeed = 1; // STANDARD IS 1.2
    controls.keys = [ 37 /*LEFT*/, 38 /*UP*/, 39 /*RIGHT*/, 40 /*DOWN*/ ];

    controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // RENDER ON CHANGE

    var button = document.getElementById( 'table' );
    button.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {

        transform( targets.table, 2000 );

    }, false );

    var button = document.getElementById( 'sphere' );
    button.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {

        transform( targets.sphere, 2000 );

    }, false );

    var button = document.getElementById( 'helix' );
    button.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {

        transform( targets.helix, 2000 );

    }, false );

    var button = document.getElementById( 'grid' );
    button.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {

        transform( targets.grid, 2000 );

    }, false );

    transform( targets.table, 5000 );

    //

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
    // WHEN PRESSED ON KEY
    window.addEventListener( 'keydown', keydown, false );

    function keydown( event ) {
    };
}

function transform( targets, duration ) {

    TWEEN.removeAll();

    for ( var i = 0; i < objects.length; i ++ ) {

        var object = objects[ i ];
        var target = targets[ i ];

        new TWEEN.Tween( object.position )
            .to( { x: target.position.x, y: target.position.y, z: target.position.z }, Math.random() * duration + duration )
            .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut )
            .start();

        new TWEEN.Tween( object.rotation )
            .to( { x: target.rotation.x, y: target.rotation.y, z: target.rotation.z }, Math.random() * duration + duration )
            .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut )
            .start();

    }
    new TWEEN.Tween( this )
        .to( {}, duration * 2 )
        .onUpdate( render )
        .start();

}

function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    TWEEN.update();
    controls.update();
}

// RENDER SCENE/CAMERA
function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
}
```

My tweets are initially in the variable data.
I now have added this to my code:

```
controls.keys = [ 37 /*LEFT*/, 38 /*UP*/, 39 /*RIGHT*/, 40 /*DOWN*/ ];
window.addEventListener( 'keydown', keydown, false );
function keydown( event ) {};
```

But now how can I navigate through the tweets (boxes) with my arrows on the keyboard? 
I want to change the css of the selected box and open an overlay of the associated tweet. (You can see this when you click on a box on the link)

I have no clue on how to start with this. Can somebody help me?

Comment: It looks like you've figured it out. I've been trying to work on it in a jsFiddle, but the external files kept changing

Comment: I think this may be the missing piece http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/MqMRz/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a stylesheet with a "selected" class, which when you click one of the elements, it removes all other instances of the class "selected" and adds ".selected" to that specific element that was clicked. Then with keyboard input, you do the same thing, but move to the next element. It could be simplified a bit with jQuery, though done without as well.

```
.element .selected {
background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
if (e.target === *element you want*)
// remove other selected classes code here.
document.addClass += " " + ".selected"
```

Comment: Yes, but my question is how to move to the next element?

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('element');

will return you a list of all of the nodes that you're trying to potentially select. Then, add event listeners of keypresses that will move though them, numerically.